# Derivative's definitions and $\Delta x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, epsilon-delta

I was teaching a friend a bit of Calculus and we came across this problem:

Given the definition $\epsilon, \delta$ of derivatives, we were searching the derivative of the function $x^2+x$ at the point $x_0=1$. So we expanded in terms of $\Delta x$ and we got $\lim_{\Delta x\to0} (\Delta x + 3)=3$, solving the problem. But he asked me why $\Delta x$ goes to zero, in the sense of disappearing in the RHS. I said to him I thought that's because of the definition of limit and I said a ''proof'' for $\lim_{\Delta x\to0} \Delta x=0$ would be something like this: for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $0<|\Delta x-0|<\delta$ implies $0<|\Delta x-0|<\epsilon$, which is true by taking $\delta=\epsilon$, and therefore the limit is zero. I think this is similar to the increment $h$ used in some textbooks I've read. But our doubt was (is): isn't $\Delta x$ a function of $x$ and if so could we use it to prove the limit as I did? I've never noticed such case, and couldn't find anywhere on the web... So I appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: No, $\Delta x$ is the increment of the variable $x$; but it is independent from $x$. It has the same status as $h$.

Comment: $\Delta x$ is not a function of $x$. Why would it be? Maybe it would be more clear if you used the letter $h$ instead of $\Delta x$.

Comment: $\Delta x$ is not a function of $x$. Perhaps we could help you more if you tell us *why* do you think it should be a function of $x$. If it were a function of $x$ then applying limits on $\Delta x$ would also require you to apply limits on $x$ itself. $x + \Delta x$ is just some number that is $\Delta x$ (signed) distance away from $x$. If $\Delta x > 0$ and $\Delta x \to 0$ (i.e. $\Delta x \to 0^+$) we have the right hand derivative and if $\Delta x <0$ then we have left hand derivative when it approaches $0$.

Comment: Perfect! I'm sorry, it was a stupid question... As soon as you guys answered it became clear to me that it is not a function. Yes that was precisely the question we pondered, we thought it could be a function for there's is an x variable, but 'tis no reason to be a function... I'm sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: Is the proof for the limit ok?